# Creating a parallax background

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

I'm trying to add a moving background in my game but I can't figure it out. The current code I use right now is this, and what this does is set a gray background color with moving clouds. This is in my GameScene.java

```
    private void createBackground() {
    pb = new ParallaxBackground(0.53f, 0.53f, 0.53f); //Background color
    Entity clouds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1000, 800, vbom);
    clouds.setAnchorCenter(0, 0);
    clouds.setAlpha(0f);
    clouds.attachChild(new Sprite(100, 500, res.cloudRegion, vbom));
    clouds.attachChild(new Sprite(300, 700, res.cloudRegion, vbom));

    clouds.attachChild(new Sprite(500, 600, res.cloudRegion, vbom));
    clouds.attachChild(new Sprite(800, 730, res.cloudRegion, vbom));

    ParallaxEntity pe = new ParallaxEntity(-0.2f, clouds);
    pb.attachParallaxEntity(pe);
    setBackground(pb);
}
```

And the cloudsRegion gets called from ResourceManager.java

```
cloudRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(
            gameObjectsAtlas, activity.getAssets(), "cloud.png");
```

I've been stuck on this for days, so if you could help that'd be great; thank you.

Comment: add clouds as ParallaxEntity to your ParallaxBackground.Try this

Answer (score 1):

What you want is AutoParallaxBackground - https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/720897f99d2c56ba357e8fe361454bd8d88c37ed/src/org/andengine/entity/scene/background/AutoParallaxBackground.java

```
pb = new AutoParallaxBackground(0.53f, 0.53f, 0.53f, 15);
```

That should be all you need to change as everything else looks fine.

I hope this has helped (albeit maybe too late)